# Is it more performant to check if ArrayList is empty before a for loop on an object that is more often empty

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, if-statement

I setup a `javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler` which listens for xml validation errors when unmarshalling an xml document.

Is there really a need to check if the `List` of `errors` `isEmpty()`?

Or should I remove it and just have the `for` loop?

I'm not sure if the `for` loop is any way more expensive than a simple `if` statement.

```
T instance = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(..);
        
if (!eventHandler.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
  for (XSDValidationEventHandler.Error error : eventHandler.getErrors()) {
    // extract error, and log it
  }
}
```

`XSDValidationEventHandler.java`, custom `ValidationEventHandler` implementation:

```
public class XSDValidationEventHandler implements javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler {

  private List<Error> errors = new ArrayList<Error>();

  @Override
  public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
    final Error error = new Error(event.getLocator().getLineNumber(), event.getMessage());
    errors.add(error);
    return true;
  }

  ..

  public class Error {

    private int lineNumber;
    private String message;
    public Error(int lineNumber, String message) {
      this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
      this.message = message;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As a note, don't name classes things that conflict with `java.lang`, such as `Error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need it in that particular scenario because the enhanced for loop won't do anything if is empty.

For other situations it *might* be needed, but I think that's extremely premature optimization, checking if for a boolean to be true or false is almost negligible.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to check the list is empty before starting the loop.

It ignore when the list size is zero. In this case, you need to check null for the list to prevent NullPointerException.